# Examples of stochastic integrals being a Lévy Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, poisson-process, levy-processes

Consider the stochastic integral:

$$X(t)=\int_0^tf(s-)dL(s)$$

with $L$ being a Lévy process (and $f$ properly chosen in order to let the SI exist).

Do there exists conditions on $f$, excluding the trivial one: $f$ is constant, such that $X$ is again a Lévy process?

In my particular interest, $L$ is a compound Poisson process. Do there exists conditions on $f$ such that $X$ is Lévy or even a compound Poisson process again?